# How to insert html-form data into three different tables at the same time?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, forms, http-post

I'm trying to `insert html-form data into a database on form submit` and then redirect the user into a confirmation page. The data from the form must be inserted into three different tables at the same time:

- the customer details must be inserted into customer table;
- the products must be inserted into ordered_product table;
- finally the invoice/confirmation information must be inserted into customer_order table.

All the data is collected from the same single form. I'm using a `Servlet` to get the data. It might be easy for you but I don't know how to insert the data in three different tables at the same time... The database is `Mysql`... Can I use `INSERT INTO` statement to accomplish this? How would I go about this?

```
// if purchase action is called
        } else if (userPath.equals("/purchase")) {

            if (cart != null) {
```

Customer Table:

```
// get customer details
       String first_name = request.getParameter("first_name");
       String last_name = request.getParameter("last_name");
       String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
       String email = request.getParameter("email");
       String address_1 = request.getParameter("address_1");
       String address_2 = request.getParameter("address_2");
       String city = request.getParameter("city");
       String State_Province_Region = request.getParameter("State_Province_Region");
       String Postal_Zip_Code = request.getParameter("Postal_Zip_Code");
       String country = request.getParameter("Country");
```

Customer_order table:

```
// get order details
    String date_created = request.getParameter("OrderDate");
    String confirmation_number = request.getParameter("confirmationNumber");
    String invoice_number = request.getParameter("invoiceNumber");
    String reference_number = request.getParameter("referenceNumber");
```

Ordered_product Table:

```
// get product details
    String product_id = request.getParameter("productId");
    String quantity = request.getParameter("quantity");
```

Redirect to confirmation.jsp

```
// when data inserted into database send user to confirmation page
                        userPath = "/confirmation";
                }
```

Comment: are you using JDBC..?

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva: Yes i'm using JDBC it is already programmed somewhere in my Servlet.

Comment: You're going to need to execute three separate `INSERT INTO` statements.  Read up on JDBC, or better yet, use Hibernate.  If you use Hibernate, then you won't have to explicitly execute three statements.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute the 3 statements into separate queries and finally redirect to the page required. just an example (didn't try).

```
    doPost(..........){

// get customer details
        String first_name = request.getParameter("first_name");
        String last_name = request.getParameter("last_name");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String address_1 = request.getParameter("address_1");
        String address_2 = request.getParameter("address_2");
        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        String State_Province_Region = request.getParameter("State_Province_Region");
        String Postal_Zip_Code = request.getParameter("Postal_Zip_Code");
        String country = request.getParameter("Country");

       // get order details
        String date_created = request.getParameter("OrderDate");
        String confirmation_number = request.getParameter("confirmationNumber");
        String invoice_number = request.getParameter("invoiceNumber");
        String reference_number = request.getParameter("referenceNumber");

    // get product details
        String product_id = request.getParameter("productId");
        String quantity = request.getParameter("quantity");


        //JDBC get connection.
        Connection conn = getConnectionData(); // I hope you already have written this part.

        Statement s1 = null;
        Statement s2 = null;
        Statement s3 = null;

        try{
            s1 = conn.createStatement();
            s2 = conn.createStatement();
            s3 = conn.createStatement();

            //insert into customer table:

            int customerInsert = s1.executeUpdate("WRITE YOUR CUSTOMER INSERT QUERY HERE");
            int productInsert = s1.executeUpdate("WRITE YOUR PRODUCT INSERT QUERY HERE");
            int orderInsert = s1.executeUpdate("WRITE YOUR ORDER INSERT QUERY HERE");

            // if all 3 inserts are fine, then return to the success page, else the error page.
            String page = "";
            if(customerInsert > 0 & productInsert > 0 & orderInsert > 0){
               page = "sucessPage.jsp";
            }else{
               page = "errorPage.jsp";
            }
            // redirect:

            response.sendRedirect(page);

        }catch(SQLException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
           s1.close();
           s2.close();
           s3.close();
        }


}
```

based on the return values of each query, you can redirect with the proper error message as well based on your requirement. hope this will help you.

Comment: Why u creating JDBC connection in a servlet, As experinced, u should guide new bee to correct programming methodlogies.

Comment: he is a new bee and should learn all the approaches. before the arrival of all those frameworks and even now the servlet is the base or the foundation. If you want to learn, first learn to fail, then correct the mistakes, compare each methodology and select the best approach. rather than sticking into one method like a robot. And I didn't want to put him into the deep sea as a new bee. that is called the experience Mr.Narendra.  it is up to him :)

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva: I already have  created a JDBC connection pool in my resources.xml... im guessing I do not need to write it in the servlet as shown in your code?

Comment: yes, that is absolutely correct! Just wanted to guide you to the flow.

Answer (score -1):

Try to get all the form data in the Servlet using request.getParameter(). Create a JDBC class(if didn't created)! Once getting all the fields, Create  a simple POJO class having getter and setter for fields u rhaving in form, Create the instance and pass this object to your JDBC class. In JDBC write 3 different insert statement to put data in your tables.
Follow this--> http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html

Follow Practice->
1. **Use prepared statement**(if u dont know benefit it worth knowing).
2. Rather sending single single var to JDBC class, **Send a Object** having all values.
3. Use a singleton approach(Read it https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton

Try to learn on your own, try these if still stuck let me know!